# Set horizontal ScrollView's height as specific indexed content height

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two FlatLists CourseView and CatagView inside a horizontal ScrollView, they have different heights, but ScrollView always adapt to the longest list which is CourseView, thus when indexed to CatagView, it has long vertical scrolling space after its list. How can I adapt the height of ScrollView to each indexed content?

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
    <CourseView ... /> //long list
    <CatagView ... /> //short list
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If you're using `react-navigation`, it may be better to make each `FlatList` a separate screen in a `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`.

Comment: Or you might be able to set a specific `height` or `flex: 1` on the `ScrollView` `style` or `contentContainerStyle`.